# Declaring global variable for all project [TypeScript]

Tags: typescript

I have created a typescript project and I'm stuck with a problem who I can't find an answer.
I would like to declare a global variable that can be read and modified by all the files in my project.
Is it possible? And if yes, how can I do that?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Global variables (outside of a global namespace you create) are in general a bad idea in JavaScript for a variety of reasons- which this renders to - but it is done all the time.  In a complex project this is likely to be a maintenance issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The goal is to create a buton in the main page to unable or disable a button in the side menu. And the unique idea that I have is to declare general variable.